# How to win when placing colored dots on a plane against one opponent?

Tags: game-theory, infinite-games

A‘s color is purple, B‘s color is green.
They alternately set a dot in their color on a set 2D-plane.
Whoever manages to

1. construct a *triangle in their own color* without a dot in the other color inside of it
2. then place a fourth dot inside of said triangle

wins the game.
Is it possible for one of the players to force their win?

Comment: **Dots on the edge don‘t count as inside the triangle!**

Comment: My initial strategy is thereby useless and I‘ve got no clue.

Comment: OK this makes more sense after your edit. Explore something like this - A puts a dot p1, B puts a dot g1. A puts a dot p2 on the line $p1g1$ on the other side of $g1$. Regardless of where B puts the dot. A puts a dot between $p1$ and $p2$ on the same line. Again next time, he can choose a dot on one side of the line. That will ensure regardless of where B puts a dot, A has at least one triangle left where he can put a dot inside the triangle.

Comment: @MathLover That strategy doesn't work, because if A does her or his first moves that way, she or he won't have won by turn 4, and B can simply arrange their first four dots in a winning configuration near g1.

Comment: @GregMartin this was just an idea to OP to explore. It is not a completely thought out strategy - as it only considers how A can win against B's defense. It does not consider B's moves to try and win. Anyway there is no strategy that any of them can adopt to win in $4$ turns.

Comment: A triangle is made of three line segments, right? So how can you construct a triangle by placing dots? Does placing dots at the **vertices** of a triangle count as "constructing a triangle"?

Comment: @bof Yes, I suppose that the triangle defined by three points is the triangle having these three points as vertices.

Comment: I think there can't be a strategy that allows B to win.  Proof:  suppose a strategy exists that guarantees the second player a win. A can then use the following strategy:  place their first point, treat it as a "dummy move", and then follow the "second-player" strategy, with B's first move as the first move of the game.  If the strategy requires them to place a point where their "dummy move" is, place a new point arbitrarily and treat it as the new "dummy move".  Using this strategy, A can guarantee a win, even though they're the first player.  Contradiction.

Comment: So this implies either than a winning strategy exists for A, or that B can force the game to continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following strategy always allows Player 1 to win in five turns, so long as points on the edges of the triangles don't count as "blocking" the triangle.  Let $x_i$ denote the $i$th point placed by Player 1, and $y_i$ denote the $i$th point placed by Player 2.

1. Players 1 and 2 each place their first two points $\{x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2\}$.  No triangles yet.
2. Player 1 places $x_3$ so that neither $y_1$ nor $y_2$ is in the interior of the triangle $x_1x_2x_3$.  Player 2 must respond by placing $y_3$ in the interior of this triangle, or Player 1 will win on the next turn.
3. Player 1 places $x_4$ in the region of intersection of the triangle $x_1x_2x_3$ and $y_1 y_2 y_3$.  This prevents Player 2 from winning on their fourth turn.  It also gives Player 1 two "empty" triangles:  the point $y_3$ is in the interior of precisely one of the triangles $x_1x_2x_4$, $x_1 x_3 x_4$, and $x_2 x_3 x_4$, and the other two triangles do not have any of Player 2's points in their interior.
4. Regardless of where Player 2 plays $y_4$, Player 1 will have one "empty" triangle in which to place $x_5$, winning the game.

Note that if one's opponent *can* block your triangles by blocking the edges (instead of needing to play in the interior of the triangle), this strategy doesn't guarantee Player 1 a win at this point:  Player 2 can place $y_4$ on common edge between the Player 1's two "empty" triangles.  I do not know how (or whether) Player 1 could guarantee a win in such a game.